# Icelandic Constitutional Assembly/Council

Tags: constitution, iceland

Are the

> (Icelandic) Constitutional Council

and the

> Constitutional Assembly

the same thing?

I tried to understand it by reading through

- the [official website](http://www.stjornlagathing.is/english/),
- the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icelandic_Constitutional_Assembly)
- and [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icelandic_constitutional_reform,_2010%E2%80%9313#Appointing_the_Constitutional_Assembly),

but couldn't make it out, because the two are never put in a direct relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two are essentially the same. The official page distinguishes between the "Constitutional Assembly," which was elected by the people, and the "Constitutional Council," which was appointed by the Althing. But there's really no difference between the two. The Supreme Court declared the Assembly elections invalid, so the "Assembly" never met. Instead, the Althing took the exact same people who won the elections and appointed them to serve as members of the Constitutional Council. The "Council" was the body that actually met and produced the constitutional amendments that were put to referendum. So, technically, the Constitutional Assembly never really existed whereas the Constitutional Council did. But the people who WOULD have served on the "Assembly" were the people who actually DID serve on the "Council." So the two are basically the same thing.

If you are going to be writing about the amendments that were proposed, you could probably save your readers a lot of confusion by just writing about what the Constitutional Council did and calling it the Constitutional Council (without ever mentioning the Constitutional Assembly). But if you have to tell the whole story, this is how you could explain the difference to your readers.